# Version control ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, git, iis, version-control, visual-studio-2017

What I'm looking for is a solution for multiple developers to work on the same asp.net application at the same time because currently I am working with another developer on the same project but we've had a couple of minor issues with overriding each others work.

I was thinking git or azure DevOps which would allow the ability to work on the same asp.net application with different developers but because we are working on the same developer server (we log in remotely into different users on the same server).
When a branch is changed within visual studio, it also changes the branch within IIS so we aren't able to work on this at the same time.

So in short the main thing I'm looking for is ability to work concurrently with multiple developers preferably on one server. I would like to know what is the standard that you use within your asp.net applications to version control your application (and your database if you do) and how you work synchronously.

Comment: “On the same developer server” is a red flag. Why cannot each of you have a virtual server to work on?

Comment: restrictions of our work environment

Comment: Agree with @LexLi, you can't have multiple people working with the same files at the same time without running into the issues you've mentioned. Normally each person has their own set of files for working on, they can branch, commit etc, and the application itself runs off it's own set of files too (else it will break all the time)